# Serialising XML file to C# objects

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following file I need to serialise to objects:

```
<constituencyResults>
  <constituencyResult seqNo="1">
    <consituencyId>2</consituencyId>
    <constituencyName>Aberconwy</constituencyName>
    <results>
        <result>
          <partyCode>LAB</partyCode>
          <votes>8994</votes>
          <share>33.00</share>
        </result>
        <result>
          <partyCode>CON</partyCode>
          <votes>7924</votes>
          <share>29.10</share>
        </result>
    </results>
  </constituencyResult>
</constituencyResults>
```

> Note: the full file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/1YFAqP3p)

How do I represent this XML as C# objects?

So far I've tried

- Paste Special As XML Classes
- SimpleXMLToCode

But neither give me the correct POCO entities I need....

I get the following classes from Paste Special As XML Classes:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class constituencyResults
{

    private constituencyResultsConstituencyResult constituencyResultField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public constituencyResultsConstituencyResult constituencyResult
    {
        get
        {
            return this.constituencyResultField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.constituencyResultField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class constituencyResultsConstituencyResult
{

    private byte consituencyIdField;

    private string constituencyNameField;

    private constituencyResultsConstituencyResultResult[] resultsField;

    private byte seqNoField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte consituencyId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.consituencyIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.consituencyIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string constituencyName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.constituencyNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.constituencyNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("result", IsNullable = false)]
    public constituencyResultsConstituencyResultResult[] results
    {
        get
        {
            return this.resultsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.resultsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte seqNo
    {
        get
        {
            return this.seqNoField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.seqNoField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class constituencyResultsConstituencyResultResult
{

    private string partyCodeField;

    private ushort votesField;

    private decimal shareField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string partyCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.partyCodeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.partyCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort votes
    {
        get
        {
            return this.votesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.votesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal share
    {
        get
        {
            return this.shareField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.shareField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When I use an `XmlSerializer` doing `(ConstituencyResults) reader.Deserialize(file);` I get:

Comment: Do you want this done at runtime or compile time?

Comment: Where did this file come from - do you have control over it? Why not just use the standard .NET Xml Serializer?

Comment: Show us the result of "Paste Special As XML Classes"

Comment: I have no control over the file, it has to look like that. I've not really used XML before (mainly used JSON) so I'm not sure. There's too much code to show `Paste Special as XML classes`

Comment: You can manually code this in 10mins. Try it. Setup C# classes match the object graph.

Comment: @loopedcode I'm a relatively new programmer & not familiar with XML...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem with "Paste XML as Classes". Just tested it on my laptop.

It failed to work because you forget to close `results` element.

Your XML must look like this :

```
<constituencyResults>
  <constituencyResult seqNo="1">
    <consituencyId>2</consituencyId>
    <constituencyName>Aberconwy</constituencyName>
    <results>
          <result>
            <partyCode>LAB</partyCode>
            <votes>8994</votes>
            <share>33.00</share>
          </result>
          <result>
            <partyCode>CON</partyCode>
            <votes>7924</votes>
            <share>29.10</share>
          </result>
        </results> <!-- Your forget to close the results element -->
    </constituencyResult>
</constituencyResults>
```

After fixing your XML, this is what I get from "Paste XML as Classes":

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class constituencyResults
{

    private constituencyResultsConstituencyResult constituencyResultField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public constituencyResultsConstituencyResult constituencyResult
    {
        get
        {
            return this.constituencyResultField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.constituencyResultField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class constituencyResultsConstituencyResult
{

    private byte consituencyIdField;

    private string constituencyNameField;

    private constituencyResultsConstituencyResultResult[] resultsField;

    private byte seqNoField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte consituencyId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.consituencyIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.consituencyIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string constituencyName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.constituencyNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.constituencyNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("result", IsNullable = false)]
    public constituencyResultsConstituencyResultResult[] results
    {
        get
        {
            return this.resultsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.resultsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte seqNo
    {
        get
        {
            return this.seqNoField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.seqNoField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class constituencyResultsConstituencyResultResult
{

    private string partyCodeField;

    private ushort votesField;

    private decimal shareField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string partyCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.partyCodeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.partyCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort votes
    {
        get
        {
            return this.votesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.votesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal share
    {
        get
        {
            return this.shareField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.shareField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use those classes I get `System.InvalidOperationException` "<constituencyResults xmlns=''> was not expected."

Comment: You must put the correct XML you're using. there is no `xmlns` in your question.

Comment: I've just checked & there is no mention of `xmlns` in the source. Yes, I made a mistake leaving out `</results>` - that was an error on my part

Comment: When did you get the exception ? When generating the class from the XML ? Or When deserializing your data from the XML ? If it's the latter one then you must create a new thread and I will answer to it because it is another issue.

Comment: I get the exception when I try doing this with an `XmlSerializer`:  `(ConstituencyResults) reader.Deserialize(file);` Thanks for your help

Comment: Yep. That is what I think :) It is another issue that is different to the initial problem. Consider creating another thread and put the code you're using to deserialize your data.

Comment: What should my question be? I will create a question now under `C#` and `XML` again...

Comment: The title should be => `[the exception type] occured while deserailizing XML file'
The in your question you put the sample XML and the C# code you're using. Don't forget to add the exact message of your exception

Comment: I've created the new thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901440/systeminvalidoperationexception-when-trying-to-deserialize-xml-to-c-sharp