# SystemInvalidOperationException when trying to deserialize XML to C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML the that looks like this:

```
<constituencyResults>
  <constituencyResult seqNo="1">
    <consituencyId>2</consituencyId>
    <constituencyName>Aberconwy</constituencyName>
    <results>
        <result>
          <partyCode>LAB</partyCode>
          <votes>8994</votes>
          <share>33.00</share>
        </result>
        <result>
          <partyCode>CON</partyCode>
          <votes>7924</votes>
          <share>29.10</share>
        </result>
    </results>
  </constituencyResult>
</constituencyResults>
```

A link to the what the whole file looks like is [here](http://pastebin.com/1YFAqP3p)

When I use Visual Studio's Paste Special As XML Classes I get the following classes:

```
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class ConstituencyResults
    {

        private constituencyResultsConstituencyResult constituencyResultField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public constituencyResultsConstituencyResult constituencyResult
        {
            get
            {
                return this.constituencyResultField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.constituencyResultField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class constituencyResultsConstituencyResult
    {

        private byte consituencyIdField;

        private string constituencyNameField;

        private constituencyResultsConstituencyResultResult[] resultsField;

        private byte seqNoField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public byte consituencyId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.consituencyIdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.consituencyIdField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string constituencyName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.constituencyNameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.constituencyNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("result", IsNullable = false)]
        public constituencyResultsConstituencyResultResult[] results
        {
            get
            {
                return this.resultsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.resultsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public byte seqNo
        {
            get
            {
                return this.seqNoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.seqNoField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class constituencyResultsConstituencyResultResult
    {

        private string partyCodeField;

        private ushort votesField;

        private decimal shareField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string partyCode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.partyCodeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.partyCodeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public ushort votes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.votesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.votesField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal share
        {
            get
            {
                return this.shareField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.shareField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to deserialise them using an `XmlSerializer` like this: `(ConstituencyResults) reader.Deserialize(file);`

I'm getting an exception saying

> `SystemInvalidOperationException` InnerException: {" was not expected."}

Can anyone help?

Comment: Again I tested it and no problem. Use the correct case `constituencyResults` and not `ConstituencyResults`as you're doing. 
Doing rename the generated classes.

Comment: @CodeNotFound that solved it, thank you. Can you write out an answer I can accept?

Comment: Just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this issue because you renamed your classes after the generation.

If you have used **"Paste XML as classes"** feature, then all generated classes should have their name respecting the same letter case as it was in the XML file.

Because you renamed the `constituencyResults` class after the generation to `ConstituencyResults` you get that error you have in your question. Notice the difference in `c` letter.

You have two solutions:

- undo your changes by renaming `ConstituencyResults` to what the genration did before your changes `constituencyResults`.
- add an `XmlElement` attribute to all modified classes, properties etc by decorating them with `XmlElement` e.g. `XmlElement("constituencyResults")` for `ConstituencyResults`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark as an answer the first question you posted before this question.

Answer (score 1):

I change your code a little bit to get your error but, from what I see, its working normally. There is the xml file name as "XMLFile1.xml", located in the bin folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ConstituencyResults>
  <ConstituencyResult SeqNo="1">
      <ConsituencyId>2</ConsituencyId>
      <ConstituencyName>Aberconwy</ConstituencyName>
      <Results>
         <Result>
            <PartyCode>LAB</PartyCode>
            <Votes>8994</Votes>
            <Share>33.00</Share>
         </Result>
         <Result>
            <PartyCode>CON</PartyCode>
            <Votes>7924</Votes>
            <Share>29.10</Share>
         </Result>
      </Results>
  </ConstituencyResult>
</ConstituencyResults>
```

This is the class "ConstituencyResults.cs" where put all your stuff. I did change the name of the variable to make it more readable.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   [SerializableAttribute()]
   [DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
   [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
   [XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
   public class ConstituencyResults
   {
      private ConstituencyResult _constituencyResultField;

      public ConstituencyResult ConstituencyResult
      {
         get { return _constituencyResultField; }
         set { _constituencyResultField = value; }
      }
   }

   [SerializableAttribute()]
   [DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
   [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
   public class ConstituencyResult
   {
      private byte _consituencyIdField;
      private string _constituencyNameField;
      private ConstituencyData[] Data;
      private byte _seqNoField;

      public byte ConsituencyId
      {
         get { return _consituencyIdField; }
         set { _consituencyIdField = value; }
      }

      public string ConstituencyName
      {
         get { return _constituencyNameField; }
         set { _constituencyNameField = value; }
      }

      [XmlArrayItemAttribute("Result", IsNullable = false)]
      public ConstituencyData[] Results
      {
        get { return Data; }
        set { Data = value; }
      }

      [XmlAttributeAttribute()]
      public byte SeqNo
      {
        get { return _seqNoField; }
        set { _seqNoField = value; }
      }
   }

   [SerializableAttribute()]
   [DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
   [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
   public class ConstituencyData
   {
      private string _partyCodeField;
      private ushort _votesField;
      private decimal _shareField;

      public string PartyCode
      {
         get { return _partyCodeField; }
         set { _partyCodeField = value; }
      }

      public ushort Votes
      {
         get { return _votesField; }
         set { _votesField = value; }
      }

      public decimal Share
      {
         get { return _shareField; }
         set { _shareField = value; }
      }
   }
}
```

The program "Program.cs" where I print the values of the object.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   public class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         XmlSerializer oSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConstituencyResults));
         FileStream oFileStream = new FileStream("XMLFile1.xml", FileMode.Open);
         ConstituencyResults obj = (ConstituencyResults)oSerializer.Deserialize(oFileStream);
         int iCnt = 0;

         Console.WriteLine("Name : " + obj.ConstituencyResult.ConstituencyName);
         Console.WriteLine("ID : " + obj.ConstituencyResult.ConsituencyId);

         foreach (var v in obj.ConstituencyResult.Results)
         {
            iCnt++;
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Record #" + iCnt.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("   PartyCode : " + v.PartyCode);
            Console.WriteLine("   Share : " + v.Share);
            Console.WriteLine("   Votes : " + v.Votes);
         }

         Console.ReadKey();
      }
   }
}
```

And the result:
[image: Console result]

In this case, I used a FileStream as your 'file' parameter.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. By putting the images as a part of your content you can make a clear answer. Thanks